# Crash - AVCaptureSessionPresentMedium in the iPhone XS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have tried to capture a video after successfully capture images and my application crash.

```
if (iSRecordVideo) {
        DLog(@"iSRecordVideo");
        //ADD AUDIO INPUT
        AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
        if (audioInput)
        {
            [[self captureSession] addInput:audioInput];
        }

        //ADD MOVIE FILE OUTPUT
        self.videoOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

        Float64 TotalSeconds = 20;          //Total seconds
        int32_t preferredTimeScale = 20;    //Frames per second
        self.maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale); //<<SET MAX DURATION
        self.videoOutput.maxRecordedDuration = self.maxDuration;
        self.videoOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;//<<SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME


        if (IS_IPHONE_X_S_MAX)
        {
            [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self captureSession] setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
        }


        if ([[self captureSession] canAddOutput:self.videoOutput])
            [[self captureSession] addOutput:self.videoOutput];

        //SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
        [self CameraSetOutputProperties:audioCaptureDevice];
    }
```

Xcode does't show any error message in the console. Please find image for more information.
[image] .

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> You can **ONLY** set a preset if canSetSessionPreset(_:) returns true
>   for that preset.

you should do

```
if([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]){
      //set the medium preset
}
```

The default value of session preset is High.

Maybe for XS max, it isn't allowing any value other than high preset.